# Use cloned repo instead of pip installed package

Tags: python

I have a Python project, which uses a 3rd party open source library, available on Github.  The library has been installed with pip3 install, and all is good.  But now I want to make some changes to the library.  So I have cloned the library repo.  But I don't know how to "tell" my Python code (which uses import ... to pull in the pip3 installed library files) to use the cloned repo instead of the library.  Suggestions please, perhaps to go about this in a different way.  I am not using a virtual environment, but perhaps I should...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the paths from which to import your modules/packages, you can use the `sys.path` list. Use:

```
 import sys
 print(sys.path)
```

to see what the path contains, and then replace the print call with some manipulation of `sys.path`, that will cause your repo instead of the standard location (often, simply prepending the path is good enough).

Of course, this should all be done before attempting to import the target package.